# Qual a melhor maneira de traduzir projetos em PHP?

Tags: php

Terminei um site do curso esses dias, e um dos requisitos era ele ter suporte a pelo menos 3 idiomas, depois de pesquisar um tempo vi que um método bastante recomendado era criar a mesma array em arquivos separados, mesmas chaves, mudando apenas o valor de cada chave, e dar o include dependendo do idioma selecionado (fiz por cookie).

Minha pergunta é: Esse foi mesmo o melhor método? Meu projeto não foi lá esse monstro gigante, mas deu uma canseira chamar cada palavra ou frase como array em cada arquivo dele.

Comment: Não existe uma solução específica que seja "a correta" pois o melhor jeito depende do projeto.  Por isso o voto de fechamento como "baseado em opinião".

Comment: O @DanielOmine está certo, tudo vai depender de como o projeto será encaminhado, muitos frameworks possuem bibliotecas, ou mesmo procedimentos próprios para internacionalizar os sites.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar o [php-gettext](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/) com suporte para arquivos .po ou .pot, parecido com o que é feito no Wordpress. Veja este guia:

```
http://www.devin.com.br/php-gettext/
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/117292)

Comment: A resposta está indicando a tecnologia buscada pelo usuário de forma direta. O link está apenas complementando a resposta.